# How to Append the elements value count

Tags: jquery, html, css

And i received a new task in jquery. I posted the code snippet until i tried.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        data: postdata,
        success: function (data) {
            var count = $('#counts').children('li span').length;
           
        }
    })
});
```

```css
li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<ul class="top-ul">
<li> </li>
<li><ul class="counts">
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
  </ul></li>
<li><ul class="counts">
  <li><span>8</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
</div>

<button class="add">
Add result
</button>
<div>
<p class="result">
</p>
</div>
```

Here after really i have no idea to do. My question was

How to append the all span elements value count to `.class` element(When clicking the button). The span elements value may change dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't uderstand your ajax  call...

Anyway you have to create a `total` variable equal to 0 first after just loop in your `span` elements and add the result in your `total`...

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add", function (e) {
    var total = 0;
    $(".counts li span").each(function(){
      total += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $(".result").text(total)
});
```

```css
li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<ul class="top-ul">
<li> </li>
<li><ul class="counts">
  <li><span>5</span></li>
  <li><span>6</span></li>
  </ul></li>
<li><ul class="counts">
  <li><span>8</span></li>
  <li><span>2</span></li>
  </ul></li>
</ul>
</div>

<button class="add">
Add result
</button>
<div>
<p class="result">
</p>
</div>
```